# Python sum time from file txt

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using a script:

```
import sys
sys.argv
 
entry = 2

t = 0
SEC = 0
min = 0
hrs = 0
 
with open (sys.argv [1]) as fp:
     for in line fp:
         entry+=1
         if entry% 8:
             continue
 
         t + = int (line)
 
sec = t% 60
t // = 60
min = t% 60
hrs = t // 60
 
print ("Total time:% d hours% 02d minutes% 02d seconds"% (hrs, min, sec)
```

Entrance:

> 315: 31: 54
>   0:00:32
>   1:11:24
>   8:18:18
>   111: 35: 56
>   112: 45: 26
>   0:21:33

of course much bigger;)

And there is an error:

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: '112:45:26\n'

I checked 10x. There are no white characters in the input txt file. So what is the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After giving some tought, the best approach for this situation is a custom converter instead of trying to adapt the ones present at Python std library

```
# you should change this to an open file - read()
dataset = """315:31:54
        00:00:32
        01:11:24
        08:18:18
        111:35:56
        112:45:26"""

acc = 0

# unfortunatelly this is a non-standard dataset of timestamps, therefore
# the best approach is to create your own converter

for line in dataset.split():
    split_time = line.split(":")
    acc += int(split_time [0]) * 60 * 60 + int(split_time [1]) * 60 + int(split_time[2])


print("total in seconds:", acc) 

>>> total in seconds: 1977810
```

Answer (score 1):

11:30:22 is not a parseable to integer string. You need first to convert your strings to timestamps, which can easely be done with time package

```
>>> import time
>>> import datetime
>>> s = "01:12:20"
>>> time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%h:%M:%s").timetuple())
```

The answer will be a numerical value which you can work with. You could also look in deltatime which may help you in your work

Comment: And can you put up this timetuple, in my script to parse every date from the txt file? Because I do not think I have to do it manually?

Comment: If your line of "times" is truthfull and not just a giberish representation of a really long dataset, then you need either to fix your dataset turning everything into times that looks like 11:22:33,11:22:34,... If it isjust a representation you can turn your string into a list of hour stamps just using THESTRINGVARIABLE.split(",")

Comment: I have a txt file with thousands of items. Will you show me how to do this automatically? I am a beginner programmer ...

Comment: Paste here at least the first 3 or five timestamps and I can help you

Comment: I can help you... Tomorrow, its very late atm for me